# Oracle SQL GROUP BY "not a GROUP BY expression" help

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table `some_table` like

```
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+
| id     | other_id | date_value          | value |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+
| 1      | 1        | 2011-04-20 21:03:05 | 104   |
| 2      | 2        | 2011-04-20 21:03:04 | 229   |
| 3      | 3        | 2011-04-20 21:03:03 | 130   |
| 4      | 1        | 2011-04-20 21:02:09 | 97    |
| 5      | 2        | 2011-04-20 21:02:08 | 65    |
| 6      | 3        | 2011-04-20 21:02:07 | 101   |
| ...    | ...      | ...                 | ...   |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+
```

And I want the latest records for the `other_id` `1`, `2`, and `3`. The obvious query I came up with is

```
SELECT id, other_id, MAX(date_value), value
  FROM some_table 
 WHERE other_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
 GROUP BY other_id
```

However it spits a "`not a GROUP BY expression`" exception. I tried adding all other fields (i.e. `id`, `value`) in the `GROUP BY` clause, but that just returns everything, exactly as if there was no `GROUP BY` clause. (Well, it does make sense too.)

So... I'm reading the Oracle SQL manual, and all I can find are some examples involving only queries with two or three columns and some i-have-never-seen-before grouping functions. How do I go and return

```
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+
| id     | other_id | date_value          | value |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+
| 1      | 1        | 2011-04-20 21:03:05 | 104   |
| 2      | 2        | 2011-04-20 21:03:04 | 229   |
| 3      | 3        | 2011-04-20 21:03:03 | 130   |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+
```

(the latest entries for each `other_id`) ? Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
 select id, other_id, date_value, value from
 (
   SELECT id, other_id, date_value, value, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by other_id order BY Date_Value desc) r
   FROM some_table 
   WHERE other_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
 )
 where r = 1
```

Comment: Why not use the MAX aggregate?

Comment: @Benoit, the `order by date_value desc` does the same thing

Comment: @Yanick Rochon: Yes, but sorting always has a cost. Probably using `MAX` is more efficient.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot SELECT any column that is not either an aggregate or computed from only the columns used in the GROUP BY clause.

However there are three ways to do it:

- You can use analytic functions

  ```
  SELECT id, other_id, date_value, value
    FROM ( SELECT id, other_id, date_value, MAX(date_value) OVER (partition by other_id) max_date, value
             FROM some_table )
   WHERE max_date = date_value;
  ```
- You can use a self join with a “greater than ” clause and detect your max this way

  ```
  SELECT t1.id, t1.other_id, t1.date_value, t1.value
    FROM some_table t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table t2
                 ON ( t1.other_id = t2.other_id AND t2.date_value > t1.date_value )
   WHERE t2.other_id IS NULL
  ```
- You can use a subquery

  ```
    WITH max AS ( SELECT other_id, MAX(date_value) FROM some_table GROUP BY other_id )
  SELECT id, other_id, date_value, value
    FROM some_table
   WHERE ( other_id, date_value ) IN ( SELECT * FROM max )
  ```

Comment: the first query ends with a `max_date not a valid identifier`

Comment: @Yanick Rochon: yes, actually this query should be nested also. I will rewrite it a bit. Do the other queries work?

Comment: yes, the second works, but slower than Michael's (0.030 ms over 0.010 ms on average)

Comment: @Yanick Rochon: No wonder, analytic functions are designed for that purpose. Self-join is therefore more costly (but it is still available if you switch to another RDBMS).

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is the simplest way

```
SELECT id, other_id, date_value, value
FROM some_table
WHERE date_value in (SELECT MAX(date_value)
                     from some_table
                     GROUP BY other_id
                     HAVING other_id in (1,2,3));
```

[Test the above query here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9579e/9/0)