# Oracle SQL group by single field and count the grouped rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, count, group-by

Consider this table `some_table`:

```
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+
| id     | other_id | date_value          | value |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+
| 1      | 1        | 2011-04-20 21:03:05 | 104   |
| 2      | 1        | 2011-04-20 21:03:04 | 229   |
| 3      | 3        | 2011-04-20 21:03:03 | 130   |
| 4      | 1        | 2011-04-20 21:02:09 | 97    |
| 5      | 2        | 2011-04-20 21:02:08 | 65    |
| 6      | 3        | 2011-04-20 21:02:07 | 101   |
| ...    | ...      | ...                 | ...   |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+
```

I want to select and group by the `other_id`, so that I only get unique `other_id`s. This query works (credit @MichaelPakhantsov):

```
select id, other_id, date_value, value from
 (
   SELECT id, other_id, date_value, value, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by other_id order BY Date_Value desc) r
   FROM some_table 
 )
 where r = 1
```

How can I get the same result, but with a count of how many rows were grouped, for each `other_id`. The desired result would look like:

```
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+-------+
| id     | other_id | date_value          | value | count |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+-------+
| 1      | 1        | 2011-04-20 21:03:05 | 104   | 3     |
| 5      | 2        | 2011-04-20 21:02:08 | 65    | 2     |
| 3      | 3        | 2011-04-20 21:03:03 | 130   | 2     |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-------+-------+
```

I've tried using `COUNT(other_id)` in both the inner and outer selects but it produces this error:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

---

Note: similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815601/oracle-sql-group-by-not-a-group-by-expression-help) (example table and answer taken from there) but that question doesn't give a count of the collapsed rows.

Comment: You will never get your expected result... In your result (id, other_id)=(2,2) doesn't *NOT* exist in your example table. It would be (5,2).

Comment: @Plouf! thanks for pointing that out, it was just a mistake in the example data (I edited it from another question) to try and make it clearer.

Comment: Also, just to make it clear, the query your are using gives you For each other_id, the id with the smallest date. :) This was just in case it is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add a

```
count(*) OVER (partition by other_id) cnt
```

to the inner query

```
select id, other_id, date_value, value, cnt from
 (
   SELECT id, other_id, date_value, value, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by other_id order BY Date_Value desc) r,
   count(*) OVER (partition by other_id) cnt
   FROM some_table 
 )
 where r = 1
```

Comment: Is it possible to group but with a condition? I have posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400235/oracle-sql-group-by-column-with-count-but-only-if-the-column-is-null-or-0

Comment: @ServerBloke aye. posted there.